# How to iterate over a JSON object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry I am a python beginner coming from a java background. I am doing something wrong and not finding it from google.

I have `config_file.json`:

```json
{
   key1: val1,
   key2: val2,
   keyArrayOfImportantVal : [ "str1", "str2", "str3"]
}
```

I am able to read in my json file and create a variable that maps to my json file

```
config_values = read_config_file('path to file') 
#config_values has json as I expect
```

I need to iterate over the values in  `keyArrayOfImportantVal`. I am just not finding what I need to do this.

I thought this should work, but it doesn't.

```
for val in config_values.keyArrayOfImportantVal:
    print (val)
```

nor does

```
importantVals = _config_values.keyArrayOfImportantVal
for val in imporantVals:
    prit(val)
```

Comment: config_values is a dictionary, so you need to index with brackets, not a dot: `config_values['keyArrayOfImportantVal']`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that should hopefully do it, but unfortunately we don't even know that for sure since we can't see how OP is reading the file. May not be parsed, it may still be a string.

Comment: I suppose you are correct @JaredSmith. I made the assumption the json file is simply being parsed as json.

Comment: Maybe out of the questions scope, wanted to let OP know about `json.loads()` from `json` library if he doesn't know about it. I find it to be the easiest method to load json files.

Comment: `JSON` in python is simply a dictionary. If you've read the file, and is same as the one you have mentioned then as @MarkMeyer said you need to access it by `config_values['keyArrayOfImportantVal']`.

Comment: If you want to iterate over all the `keys` one by one, then you can do so by `for key in config_values.keys()`

Comment: peter: Just saying "I am doing something wrong" isn't enough information. Please [edit] your question and add what the error message is that you are getting as well as the code for the `read_config_file()` function.

Comment: @Mr.Hobo No, JSON is an *encoding*, and a JSON object is *typically* (but not necessarily) decoded as a `dict`.

Comment: @chepner: "No" what exactly?

Comment: @martineau, sorry, i hit tab and didn't notice it completed to your nick, not Mr. Hobo

Comment: this comment is specific to stackoverflow admin:  how can you say I did not provide sufficient debug information?   Zvziad ansered it.   I had defined an input file.  I said I am able to read the file into a variable.  I asked how do I iterate over the variable that the JSON object is read into.  Ok I did not put the error messages on what I thought should work.  But it was so obvious the syntax was completely wrong

Comment: @petercooke it wasn't an admin it was the community that voted to close. And the fact that someone *guessed* correctly does not mean the question has sufficient detail, as i pointed out to Mark Meyer in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read how properly read json file from here [Reading and Writing JSON to a File in Python](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) or you can use this snippet if it helps

```
import json

with open('path to file') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

this will iterate all keys

```
for x in data:
    print(x)
```

this will iterate in values in this key "keyArrayOfImportantVal"

```
for x in data['keyArrayOfImportantVal']:
    print(x)
```